# I need to know how to calculate drift with a Jeppessen CR-3. Can someone help?

Tags: navigation, wind, crosswind

In my exams we are not allowed to use E-6B, just a CR-3 jeppessen flight computer and I'm having serious issues calculating W/V from other parameters like TAS/GS and HDG/TRACK.
Example:
**Q** : Given:
True HDG = 035°, TAS = 245 kt, Track (T) = 046°, GS = 220 kt.
Calculate the W/V?
**A**: 340/50kt

I need to know how to calculate Track HDG and Drift Can someone help ?

HDG-001degree TR-? Drift-05degree

What should be the Track? and what will be the Steps to solve !